# How to update an element in an array that is in an arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have made an ArrayList in Java and put some integers and some doubles in it, then I added an array of integers and an array of doubles. Now I have changed a value of one of the doubles that is in the array, and I want to update it. However, I'm having trouble with coming up with the exact syntax for it, since it's a location within an array within an ArrayList.

To be more specific, I have

```
ArrayList<Patch> patches; 
patches = new ArrayList<Patch>();  //the ArrayList of patches

int[] VisPatch;  //the array of integers that keeps track of the patchID of the visible patches
double[] formFactor;  //the array of doubles that keeps track of the formFactor for the visible patches

//these are brought in from a file using a scanner
int patchID = fin.nextInt(); //the patch number for each patch in the file
double emissionPower = fin.nextDouble();  //the emission power of the individual patch
double reflectance = fin.nextDouble();  //the reflectance of the individual patch
int numVisPatch = fin.nextInt();  //the number of patches that are 'visible' to this particular patch

//initialize the arrays that hold the visible patch parameters
VisPatch = new int[numVisPatch];
formFactor = new double[numVisPatch];

for(int i=0; i<numVisPatch; i++){
    VisPatch[i] = fin.nextInt(); //brought in from file
    formFactor[i] = fin.nextDouble();
}//end for loop

//create a new patch object from the numbers read in
patches.add(new Patch(emissionPower, reflectance, numVisPatch, VisPatch, formFactor));

//get the first visible patch in the VisPatch array
int adjacentPatchID = patches.get(maxKeyIndex).VisPatch[k]; //maxKeyIndex has been declared, and yes, we're in a for loop that uses k

//do some math on the emissionPower
double increment = 2;
double newEmissionPower = patches.get(adjacentPatchID).emissionPower + increment;

//now update the emission power of the patch
ummm...
```

I've tried

```
patches.set(adjacentPatchID, newEmissionPower);
```

and

```
patches.set(get(adjacentPatchID).emissionPower, newEmissionPower);
```

and

```
patches.set(adjacentPatchID.emissionPower, newEmissionPower);
```

but my IDE (I'm using Eclipse) just put a bunch of red squiggly lines under everything and says I don't know what I'm talking about (mainly because I don't).

Comment: What is that red message saying?

Comment: You'll find that you'll get faster and better help if you give us the errors that Eclipse is giving you.

Comment: The error message says 'The method set(int, Patch) in the type ArrayList<Patch> is not applicable for the arguments (int, double)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the thing you want to update is in the `Patch` class, not in the *list* of Patches.

You want to *get* the patch by ID (assuming your "id" in this case is its position in the list; if not, you might consider using a `Map<Integer, Patch>` instead) and then mutate it:

```
Patch patchToUpdate = patches.get(adjacentPatchId);
patchToUpdate.emissionPower = newEmissionPower;

//or if it has a proper mutator method:
patchToUpdate.setEmissionPower(newEmissionPower);
```

Comment: Are you saying I should put a method in my Patch class that will find the right patch and update its emission power?

Comment: @Tabitha: Not at all.  This is a two step operation: first, find the correct Patch from your list of patches, and then update that patch.

Comment: Oh wow, okay, I see what you are saying now and I can't believe I didn't see that before. I guess it's pretty obvious I'm new at programming, period :-P Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an `ArrayList`; It's a `List`. Meaning ... a list of things (In your case, `Patch` objects). You either need to access it via a specific index (a feature of an `ArrayList`), or iterate through it to find what you're looking for.

JavaDocs are you friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

As are the Oracle Tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: Right - but it's not accessing the ArrayList that is giving me problems - it's updating it that I'm having trouble with. I access whatever index I want just fine using 'get'. However, if I change a value that is in the array that is in the ArrayList, how do I replace the old value with the new?

Comment: `ArrayList.set()` takes an index and an object. It stores the object at the index you provide. It appears you're tying to use it like a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Aside from that ... if the object you want to modify is already in the list, you don't need to call `set()` again; you just get it from the list and modify it - you're dealing with object references.